# Масштабирование БД PostgreSQL при разработке Django проекта

Tags: python, django, django-orm, масштабирование

Стандартное масштабирование веб-приложения:

- Деплоим приложение на *n* серверов. Перед серверами ставим балансировщик нагрузки
- У БД настраиваем репликацию. Теперь в master будет идти только запись, все выборки идут с реплик. Для тяжелых аналитических запросов поднимаем отдельную реплику

Мой вопрос касается второго пункта при масштабировании Django-приложения. В Django мы не пишем sql-запросы, мы описываем модели данных используя ORM.

Можно ли настроить Django так, чтобы *запись* велась на один конкретный сервер, а все *выборки* из каких-то других серверов с репликами?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью [маршрутизаторов](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers). Пример из документации:

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'primary': {
        'NAME': 'primary',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'spam',
    },
    'replica1': {
        'NAME': 'replica1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'eggs',
    },
    'replica2': {
        'NAME': 'replica2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'bacon',
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.PrimaryReplicaRouter']
```

**router.py**

```
import random

class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a randomly-chosen replica.
        """
        return random.choice(['replica1', 'replica2'])

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to primary.
        """
        return 'primary'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        db_list = ('primary', 'replica1', 'replica2')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True
```